# Forensic Incident Response, How-To Guide/Process

Tags: computer-forensics

I'm searching for a really good source and/or book on how one responds to a computer intrusion.  I've come across many books that touch on the subject, illustrating tools and techniques to acquire forensic artifacts, but I'm searching for a how-to guide/process.

For instance, you read ... first verify that an incident has actually occurred before beginning the IR response.  What exactly do I do in this circumstance?  I'm left w/lots of choices.  Do I conduct a netstat to see if an offending IP address is presently on the box, do I evaluate the file system to see if I can find suspicious files, etc.  And of course each of these decisions has a residual effect of the data, which you'd have to explain later.  Secondarily, how do you address circumstances where many computers in a large network are affected.  If you clean one, the others may still be out there and will re-infect.  I'm searching for a source that will answer these sorts of questions.

Could someone suggest a good source of info. for this?

Answer (score 1):

The second part of your question asked about IR for identifying all hacked computers on a large network, to prevent reinfection.  FYI, here's a paper on that topic.  It's one of the earliest IR papers, but may be helpful:

"Intrusion-detection for incident-response, using a military battlefield-intelligence process"
http://seclab.cs.ucdavis.edu/papers/science.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be looking for standard-operating procedures (SOPs) for incident-response (IR), i.e., an IR cookbook.  From my experience, IR processes and techniques can vary a lot among organizations due to variations in assets protected, resources available, technical skill-level, etc.  Also, individual investigations can vary quite a bit due to types of attack, technology involved (e.g., systems and networking), security resources available, security monitoring (logs), etc.  All of this variation limits the opportunities for creating SOPs for IR.

For example, there's a great book on security monitoring from two Cisco authors.  I'd highly recommend it in general, but you may not have all the security resources and skills that they have.  What works well for them, may not be appropriate in your setting.

"Security Monitoring: Proven Methods for Incident Detection on Enterprise Networks"
[http://www.amazon.com/Security-Monitoring-Incident-Detection-Enterprise/dp/0596518161](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596518161)

Anyway, all this to say, you if you're looking for an IR cookbook solution, it may be helpful to consider these limitations for IR SOPs.